# What is the Monero testnet? How can I participate in it?

Tags: testnet

I've seen people talk about the Monero testnet, but I don't know what they mean. What is testnet? What advantages come with using testnet? Finally, how do I get involved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I know about testnet, you can run a sort of "fork" of a code with other people to test if it's works or not before you put it into an actual fork. For example, people have recently been testing Ring CT on test net to work out any bugs and then correct them.

You can connect and help the testing in the network by still using the same daemon and simplewallet program you already have downloaded. You can start syncing with the testnet daemon and wallet by using

```
./monerod --testnet
```

And

```
./monero-wallet-cli --testnet
```

There are other options you can use when regarding testnet, and you can check them out using.

```
./monerod --help
```

This is just a basic intro of just what I know, but I hope this somewhat helps.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like there is not public test net (if there is I'm interested). You can run private
https://moneroexamples.github.io/private-testnet/

Comment: Literally the selected answer in this thread tells you how to use the public testnet. There's even a testnet block explorer: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/51u6ab/check_ringct_in_action_testnet_monero_network_has/