# Using downloaded raw blockchain Setting up XMRig CPU miner (Monero)

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, mining-pool-setup

I have compiled and built a release using Visual Studio based on the windows-build guide on the github repository.

Using the xmrig.exe file I set up the option of -o as localhost:80. But this is the screenshot of what I am getting:
[image]

Is it possible to run the XMRig miner in local machine without connecting to any wallet or miner pool using the whole raw blockchain downloaded in the system? How can this blockchain can be given as input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With xmrig alone, you can't. You can set up [monero-stratum](https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum) if you would like a really simple solo mining pool.

This also requires a daemon, so you won't be mining 'fake' coins unless you joined [the testnet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/what-is-the-monero-testnet-how-can-i-participate-in-it) or the stagenet.